# Can I remove silent mode from the volume rocker?

Tags: nexus-4, vibration, silent-mode, volume

I've got a Nexus 4.  I keep accidentally going into silent mode by hitting the volume down button.  My intention is to only put it into vibrate mode though.  Is there a way I can just get rid of silent mode from the volume rocker so that I don't do this by accident anymore?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Download the app called "Vibrate mode by force" and enable the Never Silent option.

Hope it will help :)

Comment: a link to the app please?

Comment: http://www.google.com

Comment: Thanks also. I'll stop missing my calls! We should be able to disable this behaviour in the phone's options!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with the Note 3. [Shush](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.publicobject.shush&hl=en) seems to work fine. The app lets you configure after *how much time* to reenable the standard ringer, and it gives you hard-to-miss notification that the phone is in silent mode.